# How to get a <td> value after clicking the row

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I want to get the third column in a selected row.

My jQuery is

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false
            });
            $(".tweetButton").on("click", function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });

        $("#submit").click(function() {
            var MyRows = $('table#ForChangingTweet').find('tr').click(function() {
            });
            var MyIndexValue = "hai";
            for (var i = 0; i < MyRows.length; i++) {
                MyIndexValue = $(MyRows[i]).find('td:eq(2)').html();

            }
            alert(MyIndexValue);
        });
    });
```

while my table is

```
    <table cellspacing="20" class ="tweetTable" id="ForChangingTweet" >
        <caption>Tweets</caption>
        <% while(rs.next()){ %>
        <tr >
            <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
            <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="tweetButton" value="Edit Tweet" /></td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
```

My program is working fine but the loop in the jQuery is iterating through all value under third column but I want third column value on which I will click the button. In the table every row has a button as I have given the code. When o will click the button then it should give the third `<td>` of that row and it should alert through `alert(MyIndexValue);`

Can someone tell how I can get that?

```
<div id="dialog">
    <form method="post">
        <label>New Tweet:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /><input type="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Above is my dialog box which will open when I will click the 'Edit Tweet' button

Can someone help me to get the answer of this question I got stuck in this. and not getting any solution.

Comment: on click of which button?? and where is the click event for button

Answer (score 0):

You click #submit but have a .tweetButton - which is it to be? -

if tweet button it is

```
$(this).parent().prev().text();
```

If you want to click the row and get it's 3rd cell try

```
$(this).children().eq(3).text()
```

Also if you want the event handling to happen when you click submit, you need to use `event.preventDefault()`

Have a look here

There is some jQuery UI error right now, but it gives you an idea of what I mean

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qG67t/

```
var $currentTweet;
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $(".tweetButton").on("click", function () {
        $currentTweet=$(this);
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});

$("#tweetForm").on("submit",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#dialog").close();
    var MyIndexValue = $currentTweet.parent().prev().text();
    alert(MyIndexValue);
});
```

Comment: I have edited the question. now please answer based on the question. above hint is not working i have tried.

Comment: I'm afk but based in your code I think you want to save the tweetButton and use its parent's sibling in the processing

Comment: please give some solution

Comment: See update - I will try to make it work later but you have a start